# A motorboat going downstream overcame a raft at a point A (Kinematics question)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, physics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

> A motorboat going downstream overcame a raft at a point A. $T$ = $60$ min later it turned back and after some time passed the raft at a distance $l$ = $6$ km from the point $A$. Find the flow velocity.
>   Assuming duty of motorboat is constant.

This is a question from IE irodov (mechanics).

Now i tried doing this problem without using relative motion/ velocity:

[image]

Let $$\begin{align}v_r &= \text{ velocity of raft}\\
v_f &= \text{ velocity of flow}\\
v_b &= \text{ velocity of boat}\end{align}$$

Let raft reach $C$ when boat reaches $B$.
$$\therefore AB=(v_b+v_f)60\\
AC = (v_r+v_f)60\\
\implies CB = 60(v_b - v_r)$$

Now boat turns back. Let boat and raft meet at $D$ after time $t$ after the bot reaches B. Therefore:

$$(v_r + v_f)t + (v_b - v_f)t = 60(v_b - v_r)\\
\implies t = \dfrac{60(v_b - v_r)}{v_r + v_b}$$

Now, $AC + CD = 6$
$$(v_r + v_f)60 + (v_r + v_f)60\left(\dfrac{v_b - v_r}{v_b + v_r}\right) = 6$$

Simplifying for $v_f$, we get:

$$v_f = \dfrac{v_b +v_r - 10 v_b^2}{10v_b} {km\over min}$$

I cant simplify further. The answer given is 3km/hr

**EDIT**

I just realised that $v_r = 0$. Therefore last equation gives:

$$v_f = \frac{6(1-10v_b) km}{hr}$$

Comment: I believe the first problem from Irodov was similar to this. Instead of complicated algebraic manipulation so, the problem changes completely when looked at from a different point of view. The raft moves at the pace of the river, and in those 60 minutes has covered only 6 km

Comment: Oh. I just read the first line saying that it was indeed the same Irodov problem I remember !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that is quite unnecessary, really, just change the frame of reference to the river, and visualize it as a moving conveyor belt on which   the raft is merely a marked  point A.

The motorboat moves away from A for for $1$ hr on the "conveyor belt" , so it will take exactly the same time to get back to it.

In the meantime, A has moved downstream $6$ km w.r.t. the bank,
thus flow velocity $= \dfrac62 = 3\;$km/hr.

Comment: thanks this is a nice analogy, but will not using relative velocity always get me stuck in these problems?

Comment: But doesn't the raft has any velocity of its own??

Comment: The raft has zero velocity **w.r.t. to the "conveyor belt" of the river**

Comment: using my result, putting flow velocity as 3, i get $v_b = 0.05 $ kmph. Can this be true?

Comment: You said what I was going to say !

Comment: Obviously not, it would never be able to move upstream. I leave the algebraic checking for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have already given a creative solution, but if your faculty is intolerant of unorthodoxy, here is a simplified algebraic one.

I take the velocity of flow as $v$, and that of the boat as $kv$, where $k$ is a multiplier (often a very useful ploy  in simplifying), and count time in *hours* to further simplify.

Following your diagram,

Going with the flow and using relative velocities,

$AB = (k+1)v, \quad AC = v, \quad CB = kv$

For return meeting at $D$ against the flow,

$[v+ v(k-1)]t = kv \Rightarrow t = 1\quad$ (in fact we already knew this !)

Finally, as $(1+t)= 2$ hrs have elapsed from start,

$v + v  = 6, \Rightarrow v = 3$